Sequelize WHERE string LIKE `column_name`
I have table devices with models names:
+--------+-----------+
| models | id_number |
+--------+-----------+
| aaaaa  |     11111 |
| bbbbb  |     22222 |
| ccccc  |     33333 |
| ddddd  |     44444 |
+--------+-----------+

and I check whether the file path contains the model saved in the database:
/folder1/subfolder/filename_bbbbb_ver.zip
/folder1/filename_ddddd_ver.zip
/filename_aaaaa_ver.zip

for this I use this mysql query, which works very well:
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE :path LIKE CONCAT('%\\_',`models`, '\\_%')",
  { replacements: { path: el.path_name} }
)

But now I want to rewrite above query to Sequelize "object" findAll, but I'm not sure that this is possible. Now I have like this:
const model_list = await devices.findAll({
  where: {
      [el.path_name]: { [Op.like]: sequelize.fn('%\\_'+sequelize.col('models')+'\\_%') }
  }
})

But [el.path_name] but treats it as a column name, not text.

You can use Sequelize.where and Sequelize.literal for that
